# Is this a bug in Intellij Idea when using typed collection in auto-wiring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, dependencies

Here is a sample code to regenerate this:

```
package com.example.demo;

public interface Fruit {
    void describe();
}
```

Two Fruits implements this interface:

Apple Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class Apple implements Fruit{
    @Override
    public void describe() {
        System.out.println("I am an Apple");
    }
}
```

Mango Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class Mango implements Fruit{
    @Override
    public void describe() {
        System.out.println("I am a Mango");
    }
}
```

beans.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="apple" class="com.example.demo.Apple"/>
    <bean id="mango" class="com.example.demo.Mango"/>

    <bean id="fc" class="com.example.demo.FruitCollection" autowire="byType"/>

</beans>
```

FruitCollection Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

public class FruitCollection {
    List<Fruit> list;

    public FruitCollection(List<Fruit> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public FruitCollection() {

    }

    public void setList(List<Fruit> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    void describe(){
        System.out.println("size: "+ this.list.size());
        for(Fruit item: this.list){
            item.describe();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TheSpringMatrixApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TheSpringMatrixApplication.class, args);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        System.out.println("Container Loaded...");

        FruitCollection fc = context.getBean("fc", FruitCollection.class);
        fc.describe();
}
```

Output is:

```
Container Loaded...
size: 2
I am an Apple
I am a Mango
```

Problem in beans.xml(IntelliJ is showing Red color):

Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'List' type. Beans: apple,mango.
Properties: 'list'
Tag name: bean Description : Defines a single (usually named) bean.  A bean definition may
contain nested tags for constructor arguments, property values, lookup methods, and replaced
methods. Mixing constructor injection and setter injection on the same bean is explicitly
supported.

Comment: Spring Documentation Says: "Multiple bean definitions within the container may match the type specified by the setter method or constructor argument to be autowired. For arrays, collections, or Map instances, this is not necessarily a problem." So, the code is right imo, maybe it's the IDE's fault?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA